# Restricting Access to Amazon EC2 Instance Profile Credentials -does not seem to work

Tags: amazon-eks

After running the below script in the Amazon AMI Linux worker node as explained in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/restrict-ec2-credential-access.html ,

```
sudo yum install -y iptables-services

sudo yum install -y initscripts

sudo iptables --insert FORWARD 1 --in-interface eni+ --destination 169.254.169.254/32 --jump DROP

sudo iptables-save | tee /etc/sysconfig/iptables

sudo systemctl enable iptables.service
```

I am getting errors for the cert-manager-cainjector and cluster-autoscaler pods.The cert-manager-cainjector and cluster-autoscaler pods went into crashloopbackerror status with the below issue.

```
kubectl logs aws-cluster-autoscaler-5cd9d77588-tm4nz -n kube-system
```

Error from server: Get https://10.73.45.50:10250/containerLogs/kube-system/aws-cluster-autoscaler-5cd9d77588-tm4nz/aws-cluster-autoscaler: dial tcp 10.73.45.50:10250: connect: no route to host

I even tried to insert `-A FORWARD -d 169.254.169.254/32 -i eni+ -j DROP` directly into /etc/sysconfig/iptables file, restarted the iptables.service, but still no luck.

Both cert-manager-cainjector and cluster-autoscaler add-ons are configured with IRSA.

SSM add-on is configured with `hostNetwork: true` option and `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` IAM role is added to the instance profile , so that SSM daemonset can work. Instance profile has been added with IAM role for SSM because IRSA does not seem to work in SSM agent.

Is there anything that can be done to fix this connect:no route to host issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried iptables script as prebootstrapcommands in node.Then it worked.